# Save the select when reload

Tags: javascript, html

How to save my selected option in the selection box, when i reload the page with javascript location.href ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page itself has no state and won't remember anything the user did when you reload it.

If you are using a server-side language as well you can save the value somewhere on the server (a database or simple flat file), but if you just have javascript and can't save the value to the server you can take a look at [saving the value to a cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) and then restoring that value when the page reloads.

If you're feeling really adventurous, HTML5 also gives you the ability to save content to something called [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), although this is only supported by more advanced browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $_GET to send and retrieve the selection box state.

[Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ln1VT1)

Code:

```
<form>
    Select Option:<br />
    <select name="foo" id="foo">
    <?php echo_select(10); ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Do location.href" onclick='return do_foo();' />   
</form><br />
Press Button and on page-load, your selected value will be pre/auto-selected.

<script type=text/javascript>
    function do_foo(){
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
    //alert("location.href is: "+document.URL+"var="+foo);
    window.location.href = document.URL+"var="+foo;
    return false;
    }
</script>

<?php
//print_r($_GET);

function echo_select($number){
    for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
        echo "<option value=".($i+1);
        if(isset($_GET["var"]) && ($_GET["var"]==($i+1))){
            echo " selected=\"selected\"";
        }
        echo ">Text ".($i+1)."</option>";
    }
}
?>
```

Of course this snippet assumes that you use PHP to generate your form code. But let me know if you generate and process your form differently.